# Finding distance from hyperplane in libsvm

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am using LibSVM for Matlab. I want to find distances of all test points from the decision hyperplane that is created while SVM training.

How can I do so?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the official Matlab implementation provided with libvSVM?

Comment: yes I am using that... The problem comes when the testpoints are of size n ( n > 2 )....

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand `n(n>2)` - this is a matlab expression but not something that makes sense to describe a size. Can you be more clear?

Comment: The third output argument from the compiled predict mex-function (which I will refer to as libsvmpredict) gives the signed distance from the hyperplane, unless you have passed `-b 1` for training. The first output argument contains the class labels.

`[clabel, accuracy, decisionvalue] = libsvmpredict(input_args)` will give you a proportional distance from the learned hyperplane. The factor is the norm of the weight vector. To find the norm of the weight vector see here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/interpreting-distance-from-hyperplane-in-svm